# How do you force audio to come out of the iPhone speaker when a headset is attached?

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch, core-audio

I'm trying to add a loudspeaker feature to one of my iPhone apps.  I already created the recording functionality, but when I play the recorded audio it only plays to the phone headset.

What I need is the recorded file to be played on the loudspeaker, even if there is a headset attached.  How could I reroute the audio to do this?

Comment: how does i create a setting to get both if user want to use loud speaker or headset ... thanks .. sorry i miss this part.. :P

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You need to override the default audio properties using `AudioSessionSetProperty`.  Look at something like this to force all audio to go to the speaker (note that this will even happen if headphones are plugged in).

```
OSStatus err = 0;
UInt32 audioRouteOverride = kAudioSessionOverrideAudioRoute_Speaker;
err = AudioSessionSetProperty(kAudioSessionProperty_OverrideAudioRoute,sizeof(audioRouteOverride),&audioRouteOverride);
```

To detect the headphones, try this (this is literally copy/paste code off of another SO post, so caveat emptor, but it works for me):

```
/**
 * Tells us if the headset is plugged in
 */
- (BOOL) headsetIsPluggedIn
{
  BOOL returnVal = NO;

  UInt32 routeSize = sizeof(CFStringRef);
  CFStringRef route = NULL;
  OSStatus error = AudioSessionGetProperty(kAudioSessionProperty_AudioRoute, &routeSize, &route);
  if (!error && (route != NULL) && ([(NSString*)route rangeOfString:@"Head"].location != NSNotFound))
  {
    CFRelease(route);
    returnVal = YES;
  }
  return returnVal;
}
```

*EDIT:* There is a bit of a discussion in the comments about whether the CFRelease is appropriate or not.  Any hardcore Core Foundation experts care to weigh in?

Comment: how does i create a setting to get both if user want to use loud speaker or headset ... thanks .. sorry i miss this part.. :P

Comment: hie phooze.. where should i put the code osstatus above.. sorry im abit new with all these..

Comment: @shy- you put that wherever you want the overriding to start?

Comment: This will leak the `route` string if it doesn't contain @"Head".  Otherwise, nice, I did not know you can do this with the iOS SDK.

Comment: @Daniel - I originally had it next to the return, but I was crashing when the headphones were not plugged in.  I reckon it comes back as NULL otherwise?

Comment: Actually, it now occurs to me that you shouldn't be releasing this string at all, because you get the value with a "Get" function rather than a "Create" or "Copy".  See the [Core Foundation documentation](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/CoreFoundation/Conceptual/CFMemoryMgmt/Concepts/Ownership.html).  Probably the only reason it doesn't crash when you _do_ call `CFRelease` is because the string is a never-deallocated constant string.

Comment: @Daniel - the code I copy/pasted never had it in there to begin with; Leaks reported it as a leak so I tried to be clever.  Thanks for the CF documentation -- I am a Cocoa Touch guy who is slowly learning the internals as I need to :)

Comment: NB: Before executing this code, you would set the audio session category to AVAudioSessionCategoryRecord (or to the equivalent kAudioSessionCategory_PlayAndRecord)